# ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save() edu.uptc.entity.Resident

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I'm not using autoincrement in my database for this table (Residents) I'm using a VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, as de ID Column for this entity. So I don't understand why I'm getting this error when I try to add a new resident through the EntityManager.

Resident Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "residents")
public class Resident implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9052313410222202916L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "resident_id")
    private String resident_id;
```

MySql Table for Residents:

```
CREATE TABLE RESIDENTS (
resident_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
resident_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
resident_last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
resident_phone_number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
account_state_type_id INT(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (resident_id),
FOREIGN KEY (account_state_type_id) references ACCOUNT_STATE_TYPES (account_state_type_id)
);
```

The error the app throws is:

```
ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): edu.uptc.entity.Resident
```

I don't want to set my resident_id to an autoincrement I just want to add the ID that I want my resident to have. How can I fix this, It was working perfectly a few days ago, so I don't get what I am doing wrong, but I would like to

Comment: You didn't assign anything like `@GeneratedValue` to your `@Id`.

Comment: did you manually assigned an id to resident before calling save?

Comment: I found the problem, I was calling ID value from servlet using getParameter("x"). And the ID for the input in my jsp was "x" but the NAME for the input was "y". Felt ashamed